# Find the first datetime interval

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table in SQL with a column Recordtime and valueasreal

```
RecordTime           ValueAsReal
2015-11-30 12:59:00  195,6907
2015-11-30 13:00:00  203,8667
2015-11-30 13:01:00  198,0907
2015-11-30 13:02:00  198,3573
2015-11-30 13:03:00  208,064
2015-11-30 13:04:00  211,3066
2015-11-30 13:05:00  219,36
2015-11-30 13:06:00  233,4453
2015-11-30 13:07:00  232,8106
2015-11-30 13:08:00  217,872
2015-11-30 13:09:00  214,464
2015-11-30 13:10:00  200,0587
2015-11-30 13:11:00  173,776
2015-11-30 13:12:00  181,1787
```

I need to find the first 5 minute interval where the `valueasreal >= 200`, in this case the query would return

```
2015-11-30 13:03:00  208,064
2015-11-30 13:04:00  211,3066
2015-11-30 13:05:00  219,36
2015-11-30 13:06:00  233,4453
2015-11-30 13:07:00  232,8106
2015-11-30 13:08:00  217,872
```

OR

```
StartRecordTime                 EndRecordTime              AVG(ValueAsreal)
2015-11-30 13:03:00             2015-11-30 13:08:00        220.476
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Comment: The version is important as this looks like a gaps-and-islands problem. @adya, I guess you mean the first 6 consecutive values that are `> 200`? And do all rows have 1 minute difference or there may be different (larger or smaller) differences in the time values?

Comment: The version  of SQL is server 2005.

Comment: @ypercube, yes only the first 6 consecutive values taht are valueasreal >=200. All the rows have 1 minute difference

Answer (score 2):

You can find the min value for `RecordTime` where there are 6 consecutive rows by using a correlated query doing `top(6)` and then count the number of rows that is greater than or equal to `200`.

Use that min value for `RecordTime` against the table to get the 6 consecutive rows that you want.

```
-- Setup table to test on
declare @T table
(
  RecordTime datetime primary key,
  ValueAsReal decimal(7, 4)
);

-- Add some data
insert into @T(RecordTime, ValueAsReal) 
select '2015-11-30 12:59:00',  195.6907 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:00:00',  203.8667 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:01:00',  198.0907 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:02:00',  198.3573 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:03:00',  208.064  union all
select '2015-11-30 13:04:00',  211.3066 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:05:00',  219.36   union all
select '2015-11-30 13:06:00',  233.4453 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:07:00',  232.8106 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:08:00',  217.872  union all
select '2015-11-30 13:09:00',  214.464  union all
select '2015-11-30 13:10:00',  200.0587 union all
select '2015-11-30 13:11:00',  173.776  union all
select '2015-11-30 13:12:00',  181.1787;

-- Desired number of rows
declare @NumRows int;
set @NumRows = 6;

-- Min value to look for
declare @ValueAsReal decimal(7, 4);
set @ValueAsReal = 200;


-- Get the first @NumRows rows where RecordTime is greater than or equal to 
-- the min value for RecordTime where there are 6
-- consecutive values for ValueAsReal greater than or equal to @ValueAsReal
select top(@NumRows) 
  T.RecordTime,
  T.ValueAsReal
from @T as T
where T.RecordTime >= (
                      select top(1) T1.RecordTime
                      from @T as T1
                      where (
                            select count(*)
                            from (
                                 select top(@NumRows) 
                                   T2.RecordTime, 
                                   T2.ValueAsReal
                                 from @T as T2
                                 where T1.RecordTime <= T2.RecordTime
                                 order by T2.RecordTime
                                 ) as T3
                            where T3.ValueAsReal >= @ValueAsReal
                            ) = @NumRows and
                            T1.ValueAsReal >= @ValueAsReal
                      order by T1.RecordTime
                      )
order by T.RecordTime;
```

Query plan:

[image]

Comment: the code is giving me an error :database driver]')' expected (Line = 12, Col = 34) ==> "order by T2.RecordTime"

Comment: @adya you have to debug that on your side on the code that you are actually executing.

Answer (score 1):

**Query:**

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [RecordTime])
        , [RecordTime], [ValueAsReal]
    FROM @yourData
), grp as(
    SELECT n = id - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by [RecordTime])
        , id
        , c1.[RecordTime], c1.[ValueAsReal]
    FROM cte c1
    WHERE c1.ValueAsReal > 200
)
SELECT top(6) RecordTime, ValueAsReal 
FROM grp g
WHERE g.n = 
    (
        SELECT first = MIN(n) 
        FROM (
            SELECT n
            FROM grp g
            GROUP BY n
            HAVING count(*) > 5
        ) g
    ) 
ORDER BY ID
;
```

- cte orders the data by [RecordTime] in order to get consecutive numeric IDs (1, 2, 3... from 1 to id)
- grp gets data with `ValueAsReal > 200` and orders them by [RecordTime] in order to get consecutive IDs (from 1 to g minus id)
- for 2 consecutives rows, n will be identical.

  - Row 5 has id = 5 and g = 2 => 5-2=3
  - Row 6 has id = 6 and g = 3 => 6-3=3
- using GROUP BY n, you can find group with `count(*) > 5` and only keep the first `n` value (`first = min(n)`)
- last inner join output TOP(6) value with n = first

The value `6` can be replaced by a variable:

```
SELECT top(@count) RecordTime, ValueAsReal 
...
    HAVING count(*) >= @count
...
```

**Output:**

```
RecordTime                  ValueAsReal
2015-11-30 13:03:00.0000000 208,064
2015-11-30 13:04:00.0000000 211,3066
2015-11-30 13:05:00.0000000 219,36
2015-11-30 13:06:00.0000000 233,4453
2015-11-30 13:07:00.0000000 232,8106
2015-11-30 13:08:00.0000000 217,872
```

**Data:**

```
declare @yourData table
    (id int identity(0, 1), [RecordTime] datetime2, [ValueAsReal] real)
;

INSERT INTO @yourData
    ([RecordTime], [ValueAsReal])
VALUES
    ('2015-11-30 12:59:00', 195.6907),
    ('2015-11-30 13:00:00', 203.8667),
    ('2015-11-30 13:01:00', 198.0907),
    ('2015-11-30 13:02:00', 198.3573),
    ('2015-11-30 13:03:00', 208.064),
    ('2015-11-30 13:04:00', 211.3066),
    ('2015-11-30 13:05:00', 219.36),
    ('2015-11-30 13:06:00', 233.4453),
    ('2015-11-30 13:07:00', 232.8106),
    ('2015-11-30 13:08:00', 217.872),
    ('2015-11-30 13:09:00', 214.464),
    ('2015-11-30 13:10:00', 200.0587),
    ('2015-11-30 13:11:00', 173.776),
    ('2015-11-30 13:12:00', 181.1787),
;
```

Comment: fixed and awake (I hope)

Comment: Is it possible to avoid using with..as and Row_Number sysnthax.

Comment: Because the window clause in not supported in my database

Comment: It is eaiser to break the code in smaller piece using with and easier to explain how it works here.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER works with SQL 2005: https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms186734%28v=sql.90%29.aspx